Call action from RecyclerView selected Item
I am trying to develop an application that allow user to make phone call when the contact has been selected from recyclerview.
I managed to call selected user that has one number.
Here is the onBindViewHolder
I will thankfull for your help
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE:
        default:
            ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
            Contacts contacts = (com.example.myappl.Contacts) listRecycleItem.get(position);
            itemViewHolder.tvFName.setText(contacts.getFirst_name());
            itemViewHolder.tvLName.setText(contacts.getLast_name());
            itemViewHolder.tvMail.setText(contacts.getEmail());
            itemViewHolder.tvCie.setText(contacts.getCompany());
            itemViewHolder.tvTel1.setText(contacts.getPhone1());
            itemViewHolder.tvTel2.setText(contacts.getPhone2());
            itemViewHolder.tvTel3.setText(contacts.getPhone3());

    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ((Contacts) listRecycleItem.get(position)).getPhone1()));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    });
}

